# C# simple form index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, indexing

I'm a student of programming and decided to make a simple program to practice.
It's a simple form, with name, date of birth, address etc, and it's being saved in a text file (I know there are easier ways, but I want to learn all of them and started with this one =) )

I have a button to search, by name, if the person is already saved and, if yes, it's supposed to fill the form with the data.

Here's an example  of how it's saved:

```
38b7aa1f-0afb-4fe5-a8f6-40fe953eb1ca;Cindy;22/07/2005;111.111.111-11;22.222.222-2;33333-333;Testes;2112;05;Testando;Testadora;SP;cindy@gmail.com;(44)44444-4444;(55)55555-5555;True;True;Rose;26/05/1950;666.666.666-66;77.777.777-7
```

So, the name (Cindy) would be in and index[1] of an array.

The problem is this error: index was outside the bounds of the array
At this line: if (linha[1] == txtboxNome.Text)

I've searched on internet and kinda understood the problem, but still don't know how to fix it.

Can anybody help me, please?
How can I load my form properly?

Here's an print to help you "see" the program. Don't worry abou the layout, a few things get opacity 0 when running =)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNdEk.jpg

Thanks in advance =)

```
    private void pesquisarNovoBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var filePath = @"E:\Programação\WPF ConsultorioDentista\WPF ConsultorioDentista\bin\Debug\Pacientes.txt";
        string[] resultado = null;

        using (var abrirPacientes = System.IO.File.OpenText(filePath))
        {
            string lerPacientes = abrirPacientes.ReadLine();

            while (lerPacientes != null)
            {                    
                var linha = lerPacientes.Split(';');

                if (linha[1] == txtboxNome.Text)
                {
                    resultado = linha;
                    break;
                }

                lerPacientes = abrirPacientes.ReadLine();
            }

            if (resultado == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Paciente não encontrado.");
            }
            else
            {
                txtboxNome.Text = resultado[1];
                txtboxData.Text = resultado[2];
                txtboxCPF.Text = resultado[3];
                txtboxRG.Text = resultado[4];
                txtboxCEP.Text = resultado[5];
                txtboxEndereco.Text = resultado[6];
                txtboxNumero.Text = resultado[7];
                txtboxCompl.Text = resultado[8];
                txtboxBairro.Text = resultado[9];
                txtboxCidade.Text = resultado[10];
                txtboxUF.Text = resultado[11];
                txtboxEmail.Text = resultado[12];
                txtboxCel.Text = resultado[13];
                txtboxTelRes.Text = resultado[14];
                //checkBoxClinico.IsChecked = resultado[15];
                //checkBoxOrto.IsChecked = resultado[16];

                txtboxNomeResp.Text = resultado[17];
                txtboxNascResp.Text = resultado[18];
                txtboxCPFResp.Text = resultado[19];
                txtboxRGResp.Text = resultado[20];
            }
            abrirPacientes.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Attach a debugger and check the value of `lerPacientes` when the exception occurs.

Comment: Clearly `linha` doesn't have two elements in it (you're trying to access the second element).  What is the runtime value of `linha`?

Comment: Could you try to write your code in English next time, it's very difficult for non-Spanish speaking people to read Spanish code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you need to "Step Through" the application.  Set a Breakpoint (F9) on the If STatement :

```
  if (linha[1] == txtboxNome.Text)
                {
                    resultado = linha;
                    break;
                }
```

And mouse over to look at the values contained in the linha array.

Most likely you have a header in the first row of your file and it's not splitting.

Comment: Or the ReadLine method returned an empty string, perhaps for a blank line.